# Laravel json response: response()->json() or $var->toJson()

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, lumen

I'm using Laravel (in fact Lumen) for my API. I have created a `User` model and I use this to retrieve all my users:

`$users = User::all()`

Now I want to return it as json but when I read the Laravel site I see two options. Which one is the best and why, and what is the difference?

`return response()->json($users)` *(as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#json-responses))*

`return $users->toJson()` *(as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json))*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `return response()->json($users);`

only `return response()->json()` is truly http response with header `content-type: application/json`

`return $user->toJson()` just echo a string in json format. The content-type is text/html

Answer (score 2):

Actually laravel does that out of the box. just do this:

```
return $users;
```

and laravel takes care of that and returns your model collection in json.